# UrlFetchApp is not return full source code

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

If I try to simply get the source html of a page I cannot get the full source. It breaks in some point. Returns less than half of the exact source html.

```
  var pagedata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stackoverflow.com");

  var html = pagedata.getContentText();

  Logger.log(html);
```

returns:

```
[20-01-06 11:37:12:483 AST] <!DOCTYPE html>


    <html class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav">

    <head>

        <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"> 
        <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
        <meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers."/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">


        <meta property="og:type" content= "website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
        <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
        <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
        <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Stack Overflow | The World’s Largest Online Community for Developers" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=805608b6266c"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=d0797a2dd6f2" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=b556f32ececa" >


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Product/product.css?v=b21a396b1289" >

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">





        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=05e29db3ebd2" >





        <script>
        StackExchange.init({"locale":"en","serverTime":1578299832,"routeName":"Home/Index","stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","networkMetaHostname":"meta.stackexchange.com","site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"enableNewTagCreationWarning":true,"insertSpaceAfterNameTabCompletion":false,"id":1,"childUrl":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com","negativeVoteScoreFloor":null,"enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true,"protocol":"https"},"user":{"fkey":"57ec692c216f7cb3d5bad86dceda031ede043f08f80e49d7b3a503d818751da0","tid":"0e7426d0-71e0-4546-1387-57279d43b924","rep":0,"isAnonymous":true,"isAnonymousNetworkWide":true},"events":{"postType":{"question":1},"postEditionSection":{"title":1,"body":2,"tags":3}},"story":{"minCompleteBodyLength":75,"likedTagsMaxLength":300,"dislikedTagsMaxLength":300},"jobPreferences":{"maxNumDeveloperRoles":2,"maxNumIndustries":4},"svgIconPath":"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/svg-icons","svgIconHash":"53ac0f6119d0"}, {"userProfile":{"openGraphAPIKey":"4a307e43-b625-49bb-af15-ffadf2bda017"},"userMessaging":{},"tags":{},"snippets":{"renderDomain":"stacksnippets.net","snippetsEnabled":true},"slack":{"sidebarAdDismissCookie":"slack-sidebar-ad"},"site":{"allowImageUploads":true,"enableImgurHttps":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"forceHttpsImages":true,"styleCode":true},"questions":{"showPostNoticesV2":true},"paths":{},"monitoring":{"clientTimingsAbsoluteTimeout":30000,"clientTimingsDebounceTimeout":1000},"mentions":{"maxNumUsersInDropdown":50},"markdown":{"asteriskIntraWordEmphasis":true},"flags":{"allowRetractingCommentFlags":true,"allowRetractingFlags":true},"comments":{},"accounts":{"currentPasswordRequiredForChangingStackIdPassword":true}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.en.js":"e75c65979e48","js/moderator.en.js":"b6ce25c91468","js/full-anon.en.js":"bcefec08f832","js/full.en.js":"bf88016bdeb3","js/wmd.en.js":"28e8cee04c52","js/mobile.en.js":"a168d277c579","js/help.en.js":"373025d0518f","js/tageditor.en.js":"693662f7ff37","js/tageditornew.en.js":"803d1cb2516d","js/inline-tag-editing.en.js":"b5436857e5dd","js/revisions.en.js":"055fbe1202e9","js/review.en.js":"7b6845367497","js/tagsuggestions.en.js":"dba299567acf","js/post-validation.en.js":"bc3e5be5330d","js/explore-qlist.en.js":"8498d0bb288b","js/events.en.js":"57fa0feb2feb","js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js":"ab1fdc223933","js/adops.en.js":"6b9883f0531e","js/begin-edit-event.en.js":"cb9965ad8784","js/ask.en.js":"e4dd8c66240e","js/question-editor.en.js":"","js/snippet-javascript-codemirror.en.js":"07eb23cd1f61"});
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </script>
    <noscript id="noscript-css"><style>body,.top-bar{margin-top:1.9em}</style></noscript>
    </head>
        <body class="home-page unified-theme">
    <div id="notify-container"></div>
    <div id="custom-header"></div>




<header class="top-bar js-top-bar top-bar__network _fixed">
    <div class="wmx12 mx-auto grid ai-center h100" role="menubar">
        <div class="-main grid--cell">
                <a href="#" class="left-sidebar-toggle p0 ai-center jc-center js-left-sidebar-toggle" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="left-sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ps-relative"></span></a>
                <div class="topbar-dialog leftnav-dialog js-leftnav-dialog dno">
                    <div class="left-sidebar js-unpinned-left-sidebar" data-can-be="left-sidebar" data-is-here-when="sm md lg"></div>
                </div>
                                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:true, location:1, destination:8})">
                        <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
                    </a>



        </div>

            <ol class="list-reset grid gs4" role="presentation">
                <li class="grid--cell">
                    <a href="#"
                        class="-marketing-link is-selected js-gps-track js-products-menu"
                        aria-controls="products-popover"
                        data-controller="s-popover"
                        data-action="s-popover#toggle"
                        data-s-popover-placement="bottom"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:1})"
                        data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;products menu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                        Products
                    </a>
                </li>

                    <li class="grid--cell md:d-none">
                        <a href="/teams/customers" class="-marketing-link js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:7})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;customers menu click&quot;,null,null,null]">Customers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="grid--cell md:d-none">
                        <a href="/teams/use-cases" class="-marketing-link js-gps-track"
                           data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:1, destination:8})"
                           data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;use cases menu click&quot;,null,null,null]">Use cases</a>
                    </li>
```

Original source has 4168 lines. First of all there is no closing body, html tags. How can I get the full source code of a page with UrlFetchApp?

Comment: In order to retrieve the complete data, how about creating the data as a file using the script? For example, how about putting `DriveApp.createFile("sampleFilename", html, MimeType.HTML)` after the line of `var html = pagedata.getContentText();`? In this case, the file is created to the root folder. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

The Logger.log() method expects a string or other JavaScript object. The logs can only hold a limited amount of data, so avoid logging large amounts of text.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

The character limit for the logger.log function is not specified, but your variable *html* does contain all of your data.